# If font-size of body is in % percentage then is it good to use em for all things , font-size width, margin padding or % should be used at some places?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm making Fluid + responsive layout where layout scale up and down on browser/screen re-size.

If I use `font-size` of `body` is in `%`  percentage then is it good to use `em` for all things ,

- `font-size`
- `width`
- `margin`
- `padding`
- `border-width`
- `border-radius`

**Or I should use `em` only for `font-size`?**

My aim is to keep everything is in proportion when things scale up and down.

I'm little confused when I should use `em` and when `%`. My `font-size` of body is `62.5%`

Answer (score 2):

Using `em` used to be considered a good practice for accessibility before every browser supported zooming. Now I have found that it is mostly useful for easily declaring relative font sizes in specific scenarios (perhaps yours).

I've found that relative sizing does **not** yield aesthetically pleasing results on borders because some browsers will try to literally use a floating point value derived from the `em` or percentage calculation and the result will be fuzzy (try it).

I use percentages heavily in most of my layouts. I've found that a couple of generic percentage based styles can cover a multitude of layout needs (such as a style for a 50/50 split, 33/67, 25/75, etc. etc.).

I personally find percentages more intuitive to deal with. An element with a width of 100% will always take up 100% of its parent (with the right box-sizing, of course) and it's easy to read that in your code. An element that is 15em wide might take up 50% or 150% of its parent; it's not directly obvious and I find it harder to keep track of (but maybe that's just me).

Here are a few baseline styles. These haven't been tested on every possible browser/device but they are used in production applications:

```
* {
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

BODY {
    font: 11px/1.5 "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    background-color: #fff;
}

H1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin: .1em 0 .1em 0;
    color: #2B265B;
}

H2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 0 .25em 0;
    color: #303030;
}

H3 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 .25em 0;
    color: #3b5998;
}

H4 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 0 .1em 0;
    color: #666;
}

P {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA {
    border-style: solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: .2em 0 .2em 0;
    border-radius: .3em;
    -moz-border-radius: .3em;
}

INPUT[type="text"], INPUT[type="password"]{
    border-color: #85a3bf;
    width: 16em;
    padding: .2em;
    border-width: 1px;
}

INPUT[type="file"] {
    border-color: #85a3bf;
    width: 32em;
    padding: .2em;
    border-width: 1px;
}

INPUT[type="text"]:focus, INPUT[type="password"]:focus, TEXTAREA:focus {
    border-color: #0066cc;
}

INPUT[type="submit"], INPUT[type="button"] {
    border-color: #DDDDDD #BBBBBB #999999;
    border-width: 1px;
    background: #eee url([URL]) repeat-x;
    padding: .2em .8em .2em .8em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

INPUT[type="submit"]:hover, INPUT[type="button"]:hover {
    background: #eee url([URL]) repeat-x;
}

INPUT[type="submit"]:active, INPUT[type="button"]:active {
    background: #eee url([URL]) repeat-x;
}

INPUT[type="checkbox"], INPUT[type="radio"] {
    margin: 0px .5em .1em .5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

INPUT[type="image"] {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

SELECT {
    padding: .1em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DDDDDD #BBBBBB #999999;
    background: #eee url([URL]) repeat-x;
}

TEXTAREA {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #85a3bf;
    padding: .3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: but at some places I found that `%` is not giving result in proportion. specially when we use it with margin and padding around text.

Comment: @JitendraVyas - I use percents for padding/margin regularly without issue but I would be happy to look at a JS Fiddle if you want to post something which doesn't work. One thing that comes to mind with text: regardless of % or em, line-height has to be set correctly.

Comment: Do you use font-size for body in `%`?

Comment: I posted portions of my baseline stylesheet. I start with a percentage-based line-height (1.5) and an absolute pixel size for the font. Headings use em to proportionately size from that; input elements do as well, but they use pixel sizes for borders. I don't usually grow/shrink my base font size as the screen resizes, but your layout requirements may be different.

Comment: in this case I cannot scale `font-size` for other elements if i don't use `font-size` for `body` in %

Answer (score 1):

for my projects i do it this way:

- browser default font sizes are 16px
- setting `html { font-size:100.01%;}`. the 0.01% reduces the errors of the rounding off. a general "round-up" to solve the case where resizing makes the text very small at times
- using this tool: http://pxtoem.com/ you can easily convert px to ems without a hitch.
- so if i set `body {font-size: 75%;}`, the font size is 12px since 75% of 16 is 12.

px is best used for general layouting of the page like sections of the pages, margins, padding. the problem with px is, especially in browser like IE6 that have te "smallest, smaller, normal, large, and larger" text scaling, px unit fonts don't resize. however, in the advent of full page zoom, we don't need this text scaling. pages zoom, content AND text unlike the old days.

ems are best used in padding and margins of text as well as the font size of the text. in the case of the IE text scaling, ems DO resize in response to that.

percent? i don't use them or rarely in some cases.